# how can I quickly get to Manage saved passwords in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, google-chrome-os

you have to goto preferences, then show advanced settngs, then click on Manage saved passwords.  can I create a shortcut button or key command to open that quickly.  I want to use it over and over and can't do that 3 step navigation each time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From my knowledge (and a little bit of Google), there's no keyboard shortcut to open up your saved passwords.

You can however, paste this URL into your address bar to quickly open up your saved passwords:

- **`chrome://settings/passwords`**

I suggest bookmarking that URL and placing it on your bookmarks bar. That way you can quickly access your passwords at the click of a button.

Comment: Is there a way to put something in the search box also? Like the host for the current url?

Comment: Beauty!  I do this ten times a day... @user447607, I think you'd have to write a plugin for that

Answer (score 1):

You can also go to [passwords.google.com](https://passwords.google.com/) and sign in with the same account you use in Google Chrome.

Comment: doesnt work if you have a sync passphrase: `Google can't check your passwords for security issues, because you set up a passphrase to encrypt your passwords in your Google Account. This keeps the data private to you.`

Answer (score 0):

To access your stored passwords in Chrome more recently, you should use the following internal link: chrome://password-manager/passwords.

Additionally, consider utilizing a bookmark tool that allows for custom shortcuts, such as Quickey, available at this link:

https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/quickey-%E2%80%93-the-quick-tab-s/ldlghkoiihaelfnggonhjnfiabmaficg

That is how I like to do it !